# COUNT() is higher than total number of rows in table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table that when viewed using phpMyAdmin, reportedly has 293408 records...

```
SELECT * FROM resorders
```

`Showing rows 0 - 24 (293408 total, Query took 0.0003 seconds.)`

However, when I use the COUNT() function to count the rows, it's reporting a much larger value...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resorders
```

`COUNT(*)
  332994`

Any idea why the discrepancy?  I guess if one is to have any faith in the accuracy of the database, one would have to assume that the count reported by the web interface is wrong and the count returned by the query is accurate...  But I find it kind of disturbing.

Comment: because in phpmyadmin defaul limit applied in listing, where in count limit does not applied. But 293408 total and COUNT(*) 332994 should always be same.

Comment: I would go with the `COUNT(*)` approach. We don't know what method PMA uses to estimate the total and functions such as mysqli_num_rows and PDOStatement::rowCount cannot be relied upon for the correct count.